# 1:N or N:1 relations of two objects in Angular2 as observables from a http request

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Referring to the "[Tour of heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)" from the angular tutorial.

Assumed that we'll give all existing heroes the possibility to wear a special suite, but any other hero can wear the same suite too. We really don't want them to be naked. In this case we would have a related data object that holds all information’s about the available suits. The hero itself has to know which suite he is wearing and where he can find his selected one. For this case we would create a property that holds the ID of his chosen dress.

What would be the right way to resolve the relation between the hero and his suite in Angular as observable from http request?

E.g:

`app/hero.ts`

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  suiteId: number;
}
```

`app/suit.ts`

```
export class Suite {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  material: string;
  color: string;
}
```

`app/in-memory-data.service.ts`

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let heroes = [
      {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', suitId: 11},
      {id: 12, name: 'Narco', suitId: 12}
    ];
    let suits= [
      {id: 11, name: 'Nice and blue', material: 'Cotton', color: 'blue'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Sexy and red', material: 'Silk', color: 'red'}
    ];
    return {heroes, suits};
  }
}
```

I know that something like next code block will work, but I would like to know how to resolve this the “observable” way.

```
// ...
getHeroesWithSuit(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
    .map( response  => response.json().data as Hero[])
    .do( response => response.forEach( ( data ) => data.suite = this.suiteService
      .getSuit(data.suiteId)
      .subscribe(suite => data.suite = suite as Suite)
    ))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
// ...
```

Comment: Where do you call/need `getHeroesWithSuit`? What's the logic here? Excuse me if I'm not getting something obvious but the question seems a little vague. What I did understand is that there are `heroes` and `suits`; `suits` have `id`s and you assign these `id`s to `heroes`. Then what?

Comment: I guess, technically it doesn't matter where to call the `getHeroesWithSuit` method,  possibly in a service that provides data on a request from a component. Lets assume that we want to display the suit that some hero is wearing in the detail and list component. It was purposeful that this question is vague, because this topic is in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the method `getHeroesWithSuit()` does two tasks.

1. get the list of heroes.
2. get suite details for each hero.

And as we want to combine this two operations we need to use `flatMap` and `forkJoin` operators. Using these two operators `getHeroesWithSuit()` function can be written in Observable way like this.

```
    getHeroesWithSuit(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
      .flatMap((heroes: Heroes[]) => Observable.forkJoin(heroes.map((hero: Hero) => {
          return this.suiteService.getSuit(hero.suiteId)
            .map((suite: Suite) => {
              hero.suite = suite;
              return hero;
            });
        }))
       );
     }
```

`flatMap` Operator lets you chain two Observables, returning a new Observable. here we are chaining the result of retrieve heroes service to the forkJoined observable.

And then we have mapped each hero to the `getSuite()` method of the `suiteServices` and passed the result to the `forkJoin` operator.

the above code snippet represent the **N:1** relation where each hero has one suite.

but what if each hero has multiple suites and `suiteId` field of `Hero` class is an Array.In that case we have to use `forkJoin` operator one more time to retrieve info of all suites for each hero.

In this `forkJoin` we will map all the `suiteId` of each hero to the `getSuit()` method of `suiteServices`. And this will be the **1:N** relation between objects.The update `getHeroesWithSuit()` function will look like this.

```
  getHeroesWithSuit():Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
      .flatMap(
        (heroes:Heroes[]) => Observable.forkJoin(heroes.map(
          (hero:Hero) => {
            return Observable.forkJoin(hero.suiteIds.map(
              suiteId => {
                return this.suiteService.getSuit(suiteId)
              }
            )).map(
              suites => {
                hero.suites = suites;
                return hero;
              })
          }
        ))
      );
  }
```

here is the [reference link](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/) it has good explanation of operators and how to use them to combine multiple Observable. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Guess you are describing a N:1 relation (many heroes can wear the same suit). How would the other direction look like? I mean 1:N (one hero can where many parts of a suits e.g.: gloves, t-shirts, … ). Sure the `suitId: [1,2,3]` has to be an array then. What is next? I will update my question later, too.

Comment: well, for 1:N relation we can have one more fork join to retrieve all suites info for each hero. I am updating my answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain 1:N relation scenario.

Comment: This is definitely an upvote! :-) Tomorrow I'll check if everything is working as expected. One more question wouldn't it be better to make the http request once instead of doing it for every ID when resolving the 1:N relationships of `suiteID`? Thanks for your detailed awnser!

Comment: yes of course, if you have another service which can take array of suite ids and returns array of suite objects then you should definitely use that service and in that case we don't need this one extra forkJoin the code will look same like the one for N:1 relation.

Comment: N:1 relation, a hero can have one suite is working. Except that you have a literal error in your code snippet, it should be `this.suiteService.getSuit(hero.suiteId)` and not `data.suiteId`. Same in the secon example for 1:N. Can you change that please. I will check the second one now. :-)

Comment: Thank you, the second example is working great too! You saved my live i will never see an hero naked. Puuuh. ;-) This bounty is definitely yours!